# How to get the tag values of the parent tag when parent tag attribute value is unique?

Tags: java, groovy, automation, soapui

I have a SOAP XML data like this.

```
<Results>
    <ResultSet fetchSize="10">
             <Row rowNumber="1">
                <REL_ID>22439129</REL_ID>
                <EFF_TMSTP>2015-09-14 07:08:31.246</EFF_TMSTP>
                <RETIRED_TRAN_ID>63859659</RETIRED_TRAN_ID>
                <OBJ_ID>1371718</OBJ_ID>
                <REL_OBJ_ID>1350658</REL_OBJ_ID>
                <CUST_VIEW_CD>CORE</CUST_VIEW_CD>
                <CUST_MODEL_CD>CESE</CUST_MODEL_CD>
                <TYPE_CD>DRVD</TYPE_CD>
                <UNLINK_FLG>N</UNLINK_FLG>
                <EXPR_TMSTP>9999-12-31 23:59:59.999</EXPR_TMSTP>
                <TRAN_TMSTP>2015-09-14 07:08:31.246</TRAN_TMSTP>
                <RETIRED_TRAN_TMSTP>9999-12-31 23:59:59.999</RETIRED_TRAN_TMSTP>
                <TRAN_ID>63859659</TRAN_ID>
            </Row>
            <Row rowNumber="2">
                <REL_ID>22482704</REL_ID>
                <EFF_TMSTP>2015-09-24 06:27:43.358</EFF_TMSTP>
                <RETIRED_TRAN_ID>64285012</RETIRED_TRAN_ID>
                <OBJ_ID>11983064</OBJ_ID>
                <REL_OBJ_ID>1350658</REL_OBJ_ID>
                <CUST_VIEW_CD>CORE</CUST_VIEW_CD>
                <CUST_MODEL_CD>CESE</CUST_MODEL_CD>
                <TYPE_CD>DRVD</TYPE_CD>
                <UNLINK_FLG>N</UNLINK_FLG>
                <EXPR_TMSTP>9999-12-31 23:59:59.999</EXPR_TMSTP>
                <TRAN_TMSTP>2015-09-24 06:27:43.358</TRAN_TMSTP>
                <RETIRED_TRAN_TMSTP>9999-12-31 23:59:59.999</RETIRED_TRAN_TMSTP>
                <TRAN_ID>64285012</TRAN_ID>
            </Row>
            <Row rowNumber="3">
                <REL_ID>25372326</REL_ID>
                <EFF_TMSTP>2016-07-08 04:46:02.591</EFF_TMSTP>
                <RETIRED_TRAN_ID>81170279</RETIRED_TRAN_ID>
                <OBJ_ID>13613079</OBJ_ID>
                <REL_OBJ_ID>1350658</REL_OBJ_ID>
                <CUST_VIEW_CD>CORE</CUST_VIEW_CD>
                <CUST_MODEL_CD>CI</CUST_MODEL_CD>
                <TYPE_CD>DRVD</TYPE_CD>
                <UNLINK_FLG>N</UNLINK_FLG>
                <EXPR_TMSTP>9999-12-31 23:59:59.999</EXPR_TMSTP>
                <TRAN_TMSTP>2016-07-08 04:46:02.595</TRAN_TMSTP>
                <RETIRED_TRAN_TMSTP>9999-12-31 23:59:59.999</RETIRED_TRAN_TMSTP>
                <TRAN_ID>81170279</TRAN_ID>
            </Row>
    </ResultSet>
</Results>
```

From the above response / XML , I have to collect **OBJ_ID,REL_OBJ_ID,** **CUST_MODEL_CD** and **TYPE_CD** tag values from each Row Set as these four values will be passed to the another WebService Request as a parameters.

**FYI: I'm using this thru Groovy Scripting in SOAPUI tool.**

If you provide the any sample for this, will be helpful for me..

Thanks

Comment: Make sure your XML is valid (it should ends with `</Results>` not `<Results>`).

Comment: Its a copy paste mistake...I'm getting the proper response with all the tags are closed.

Comment: @Karunagara, since there are three `Row`'s, do you want send the following web service request 3 times(the number of times equal to response Row count) in a loop?

Comment: Yes.I have to collect the FOUR tag values from each row from the response. i.e. above mentioned XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your XML document is valid you can get a List of all `OBJ_ID` (as an example) like so:

```
def xml = '''<Results>...</Results>'''
def results = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
results?.ResultSet?.Row?.OBJ_ID.each {
    println(it)
}
```

The above code should prints:

```
1371718
11983064
13613079
```

if you want to collect them:

```
List objIds = results?.ResultSet?.Row?.OBJ_ID.collect{it}
println(objIds)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def responseHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( messageExchange.responseContent )

if (responseHolder != null)
{
 def results = new XmlSlurper().parseText(responseHolder)
 results?.ResultSet?.Row?.OBJ_ID.each {
      println(it)
 }
}
else
{
 log.info("No Response Found")
}

For the above script, I'm getting NULL in 'results'. But if I remove those "XmlSlurper()" part and added this ->  def ARR_OBJ_ID = responseHolder.getNodeValues("//OBJ_ID")
 log.info (ARR_OBJ_ID[0])...I'm getting value...

Comment: @Karunagara using your code above it should works, it doesn't there is something different at your side which we can't see it here, try your code somewhere out of your context it check if it has something to do with GroovyUtils(context), and protect parserText() block with try/catch to see if something come up.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should collect reqiored fields:

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(resultsText)
List<groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild> list =
        xml?.ResultSet?.Row?.collect{it.OBJ_ID + it.REL_OBJ_ID + it.CUST_MODEL_CD + it.TYPE_CD}
```

Output `list.toString()`:

```
[[1371718, 1350658, CESE, DRVD], [11983064, 1350658, CESE, DRVD], [13613079, 1350658, CI, DRVD]]
```

For script Assertion and provided response:

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(messageExchange.response.responseContent)
List<groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild> list =
        xml?.ResultSet?.Row?.collect{it.OBJ_ID + it.REL_OBJ_ID + it.CUST_MODEL_CD + it.TYPE_CD}
assert !(list.isEmpty())        
assert (list.size() == 3)
```

Comment: I'm not getting any value in the list while running Script Assertion

Comment: edited my answer for Scrip Assertion. I have valid asserts

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If I use this script, I can get only OBJ_ID not all. Why? def results = new XmlSlurper().parseText( messageExchange.response.responseContent )
List objIds = results?.ResultSet?.Row?.collect{it.OBJ_ID + it.REL_OBJ_ID + it.CUST_MODEL_CD + it.TYPE_CD}
log.info(objIds)

Comment: Hard to say, maybe some "inner kitten" in soapui and groovy. In simple script it works. Maybe it will be OK to collect values as string and assert them? Like this: `xml?.ResultSet?.Row?.collect{"${it.OBJ_ID} ${it.REL_OBJ_ID} ${it.CUST_MODEL_CD} ${it.TYPE_CD}"}`  .... `assert (list.toString() == "[1371718 1350658 CESE DRVD, 11983064 1350658 CESE DRVD, 13613079 1350658 CI DRVD]")`